# How to find the sum of this Convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am given the following convergent series asked to find the value of:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{4n}{(n^4+n^2 +1)}\right)$$

According to Sum calculators, I have found the value to be 2. Though, I don't know what approach to take to prove this. To aid us in the question, we've been given the following hint:

$$n^4 + n^2 + 1 = (n^2 + 1)^2 − n^2$$

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

$$n^4+n^2+1=$$
$$(n^2+n+1)(n^2-n+1)$$

$$\frac{1}{n^2-n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2-(n+1)+1}=$$

$$\frac{2n}{n^4+n^2+1}$$

Think telescoping.
You will find $2$.

Comment: Before answering what is likely a duplicate question, search for similar questions already asked.

Answer (score 0):

Further hint:
$$ \frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1} = \frac{n}{(n^2+1)^2-n^2} = \frac{n}{(n^2+1-n)(n^2+1+n)} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{n^2-n+1} - \frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right). $$